# awk command to find name of text pattern occurring more than once

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text file, which contains list of all the files, the file name are as follows

```
Test.java_v1 
Test.java_v1_v1 
Real.cbs_v2_v2
```

how do I find the name of the files which have more that one "_" in their **extension** using awk??

I want the `_` after the `.` to be taken into consideration.

```
Test_1.java_v1
Test.java_V1_V1
Real.cbs_v2_v2
```

The output should not contain `Test_1.java_v1`, how would I do that ?

Answer (score 5):

**Answer for new requirement to consider only file extention for check**

Using `awk`

```
awk -F'.' '$2~/_.*_/' file
```

Test

```
% cat file 
Test.java_v1
Test_1.java_v1
Test.java_v1_v1
Real.cbs_v2_v2

% awk -F'.' '$2~/_.*_/' file
Test.java_v1_v1
Real.cbs_v2_v2
```

---

Using `sed`

```
sed -n 's/.*\.//; /_.*_/p' file
```

---

Using `grep`

```
grep '.*\..*_.*_' file
```

---

**Answer for old requirement to consider file names for check**

Using `awk`

```
awk -F'_' 'NF>2' file
```

Output:

```
Test.java_v1_v1
Real.cbs_v2_v2
```

**Short Description**

`-F'_'` - separate fields with `_`.

`NF` - number of fields

`'NF>2'` - short form of `NF>2 {print $0}` - print lines satisfying condition `NF>2`

Here, number of `_` is equal to `NF-1`. If you want to check for `#'_'>1`, you need to check for `NF>2`

Comment: This seems to work, but if my file name may contain "_" like Test_1.java_v1 in this case the commands wouldn't work right ??

Comment: @davidxavier that's right. Please update your question with this addition requirement and I would post updated ans...

Comment: I need to check for "_" after the extension i.e after "." , file name which contain "_" should not be considered.

Comment: @davidxavier content after `.` is called file **extension** not file *name*! You could have used this word in question to make it more clear!

Comment: yes it but can u explain it for me what if I want to extend the logic for three_ ??

Comment: @davidxavier for three `_` change `_.*_` to `_.*_.*_` just as many `_` as you want. I thought it was straight forward!